# Python Flask app route is not working well

Tags: python, flask, routes

I tried to find a solution for my problem in other questions but I couldn't.

I downloaded the python flask and made my first flask app and it ran fine.

Here is the code:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello, world!"
```

When I ran my second file where I had added an `app.route ("/ david")` and followed the same procedure again, refreshed it and nothing changed.

That is to say, I was going to `/ david` and I  get an URL error
Here is my second file

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello, world!"

@app.route("/david")
def david():
    return "Hello, David!"
```

I tried the same with other files which have some added routes and the result is the same as the first file

Thanks for your answers, I hope to solve my problem.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not run the app. What you did is just create a structure for flask, but did not start the server.

Just add:

```
app.run()
```

To the bottom of the file and it will work. It will with start the flask server at http://localhost:5000.

By default, flask runs on port 5000.

It can be changed by:

```
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=xxxx)
```

`0.0.0.0` means it accepts request from anywhere on the port specified.

Make sure you have all the permissions and nothing else is running if you want it to run on port 80.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: i run app using command line . I go to folder , and type " env FLASK_APP=application.py flask run" . The problem is port 5000  is not refresh the result and i have the same result as the first program .Thanks for your answer anyway

Comment: If you add a new route, you need to stop and restart flask.

Comment: When you run "flask run" it will display something like this: "* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)".

Comment: So press CTRL+C and run "flask run" again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try first by restarting your IDE; this worked for me. If that doesn't work, try clearing your ports for Windows:

- Open Task manager
- Click on the “Processe”  tab
- Enable the "PID" column: View -> Select Columns -> Check the box for PID
- Find the PID (in your case, 5000 - flask default port) and click “END PROCESS"